# How to move selected columns of a DataFrame to the end of it (re arranging the column positions)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

I am trying to ingest a RDBMS (Greenplum) table into Hive. I read the table and obtain a dataFrame from it as below:

```
val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                                                   .option("dbtable", "(select * from schema.table where source_system_name='DB2' and period_year='2017') as year2017")
                                                   .option("user", devUserName)
                                                   .option("password", devPassword)
                                                   .option("numPartitions",15)
                                                   .load()
```

The schema of the above DF is:

```
forecast_id:bigint
period_year:numeric(15,0)
period_num:numeric(15,0)
period_name:character varying(15)
source_system_name:character varying(30)
source_record_type:character varying(30)
ptd_balance:numeric
xx_data_hash_id:bigint
xx_pk_id:bigint
```

In order to ingest the above dataframe into hive, I took the schema into a list and changed all the greenplum datatypes to hive compatible datatypes.
I have a map: `dataMapper` which tells what datatype of gp should converted into Hive's

```
class ChangeDataTypes(val gpColumnDetails: List[String], val dataMapper: Map[String, String]) {
  val dataMap: Map[String, String] = dataMapper
  def gpDetails(): String = {
    val hiveDataTypes = gpColumnDetails.map(_.split(":\\s*")).map(s => s(0) + " " + dMap(s(1))).mkString(",")
    hiveDataTypes
  }
  def dMap(gpColType: String): String = {
    val patterns = dataMap.keySet
    val mkey = patterns.dropWhile{
      p => gpColType != p.r.findFirstIn(gpColType).getOrElse("")
    }.headOption match {
      case Some(p) => p
      case None => ""
    }
    dataMap.getOrElse(mkey, "n/a")
  }
}
```

These are the datatypes after the above code executes:

```
forecast_id:bigint
period_year:bigint
period_num:bigint
period_name:String
source_system_name:String
source_record_type:String
ptd_balance:double
xx_data_hash_id:bigint
xx_pk_id:bigint
```

As my Hive table is partitioned dynamically based on source_system_name & period_year, I need to change the content of the dataframe by moving the column data: `source_system_name & period_year` to the end of the dataframe as the partition columns of the hive table should be the last ones of the table when it is dynamically partitioned while inserting the data in it.

Could anyone tell me how can I move the columns: source_system_name & period_year of the dataframe: yearDF from their current position to the end of it (essentially re arranging the columns) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract your columns from main list, then append at the end and perform select on your DataFrame:

```
val lastCols = Seq("col1","col2")
val allColOrdered = df.columns.diff(lastCols) ++ lastCols
val allCols = allColOrdered.map(cn => org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(cn))
val result = df.select(allCols: _*)
```

Comment: It worked..Much appreciated..